# Is "fat' in "You are not fat" being used as a noun?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

Since "fat" can be used as a noun, "You are not fat" with 
fat being used as a **noun** would still be grammatically correct wouldn't it?

Because you can say "You are not ice." or "You are not glue." or "You are not lava." Meaning you are not the noun in the sentence. Do you need to specify with an article and say "You are not the fat"?

Comment: It will depend on the type of noun you are using. Nouns like *ice*, *glue*, and *lava* are [noncount](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/noncountnoun.htm), which is related to why they don't require an article before them.

Comment: *Fat* is not ordinarily used as a noun in the sense *fat person*, only *fatty substance* -- the stuff on the outside of your steak. It would take a very far-fetched set of circumstances for "You are not fat" to be taken in any sense except adjectival.

Comment: @StoneyB The nonsensicality (nonsensicalness?) struck me as well, but the OP seems to recognize that, as he gave similarly nonsensical examples that we wouldn't normally equate a person to (ice, glue, lava). He or she seems aware that it's unusual to say a person is (**the noun**) fat. I think this is more of an article question in disguise.

Comment: @StoneyB At least in abstract terms, I can think of an example of a person (at least indirectly) being referred to as "fat."  

**John**: I can't believe I lost my job. And the arrogant CEO described the layoffs as just "trimming the fat."  
**Sue**: You're not fat. You'll find a better job.

Comment: @pyobum I was asking in seriousness.

Comment: @user18696 I wasn't questioning the seriousness (or sincerity) of your question, but you should recognize that it's *at least* unusual to refer to people using the noun *fat*.

Comment: @StoneyB That's where my confusion comes in. There was a poster somewhere that said "You are not fat. You have fat." but many said it was incorrect. So you can't use "fat" in this instance without an article?

Comment: You need to incorporate a context -- @pyobum's example would do, or a longer citation of your original source -- in which using *You are not fat* has some colour of rationality. The use of articles is driven by discourse context, so your question is essentially meaningless as it stands.

Comment: @pyobum Not unusual until it was pointed out to me. English breaks a lot of  it's own rules, so I assumed it was correct due to intention. But now I'm just confused.

Comment: @StoneyB The context would be the follow up sentence "you have fat" which determines that the writer in using the noun form, would it not. Or is it too vague to be considered context?

Comment: @user18696 We can't know with certainty the intention of the writer without asking the person directly. The writer could have intended *fat* as either an adjective or a noun in the first sentence. The structure of the sentence allows for ambiguity, the context provided by the second sentence notwithstanding.

Comment: @pyobum The intent is clear by readers of the poster that the writer is referring to the noun, it's implied. Does the ambiguity make it grammatically incorrect, or just vague?

Comment: @user18696 As you've described it, I'm not convinced that *fat* is clearly intended as a noun on the poster in the first sentence. But assuming the writer **did** intend to use it as a noun, *it is grammatically correct* for there to be **no** article before *fat*, for the reason I mentioned in my very first comment above. (It is a noncount noun.)

Comment: You can use it that way, and intend it as a noun, but 100% of the people hearing you will hear it as an adjective. So you will have to explain it to them.

Comment: Much of the discussion above notwithstanding, the OP asked perfectly clearly whether or not "You are not fat" is grammatical with *fat* being a noun. That it would be less common than if *fat* were used as an adjective, that arguably only makes it a more interesting question. It's hard to see how it can be deemed "primarily" a question about articles, and therefore how it could be a duplicate of such a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not fat.

The sentence is in the pattern of be + adj. You can form sentences with be + noun such as "you are a boy/you are not a boy" (countable singular noun). So the OP's sentence presented above, though funny and nonsensical, is grammatically correct with  the word "fat" used as a noun. You don't need to put the definite article "the" before this uncountable noun in this sentence. I don't mean that you cannot put "the" before an uncountable noun. You can do so when you want to specify it. Look at the following examples: I have money. I have spent the money you gave me. I have drunk the milk I bought yesterday.

Comment: It will be nice of you  if you tell us the reason for this downvote.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote it, but I'd point out that if *fat* is a noun, it's not in the pattern of *be + adj.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use "fat" as a noun without an article. The word "fat" can be [countable or uncountable](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/fat_2), depending on the usage. In everyday speech, it's uncountable, and refers to body fat in animals, both the kind in our bodies and the kind in meat. Here's an [example](http://www.calorieking.com/learnabouts/Dietary-Guidelines-Explained-Recommended-fat-intake_OTc1.html) referring to food:

> Most people eat too much fat.

And [here's one](http://www.fitnessmagazine.com/workout/arms/exercises/7-move-firm-arms-workout/) referring to humans:

> These biceps and triceps exercises will help you get rid of arm fat and tone sleek muscles.

In [chemistry](http://www.chemistryexplained.com/Di-Fa/Fats-and-Fatty-Acids.html), "fat" is often countable, and refers to a type of molecule:

> A fat (or oil) is formed when three fatty acid molecules react with a glycerol molecule to yield a triglyceride (and three water molecules).

Here's another countable example from a [cooking site](http://www.seriouseats.com/2014/05/cooking-fats-101-whats-a-smoke-point-and-why-does-it-matter.html):

> One of the most important things you'll want to consider when picking out a fat is smoke point.